# Linux: find files *.log in directory trees and write 10 last lines in each

Tags: linux

I need to find all files, that ends with .log in directory /var and all its trees-directories; and to write ten last lines of each of these *.log files

---

`cd /var
sudo find -name '*.log' -print`

---

This command allows me to find these files. What I see is:

`./log/auth.log
./log/Xorg.0.log
....
./log/apt/term.log
.log/alternatives.log`

I've tried to use
`for var in sudo find -name '*.log'; do tail -n 10 $var; done` to print the lines, but there was an error. So what command should I use in order to find files and print the lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this**:

```
find /var -name "*.log" -type f -exec tail '{}' +
```

**Explanation**:

`-type f` - find only files

`-exec <command> {} +` - execute command. See man find for more information

**Or**:

```
for i in $(find /var -name "*.log" -type f); do echo $i; tail $i; done
```

Gets the same output but with slight format difference